# why wont jquery work on my js fiddle?

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

this is a very simple question, I have never gotten jquery selectors to work on jsfiddle and I still dont know why. I don't think there's anything wrong with my code, but its not outputting what its supposed to in my firebug console. Not even a simple id selector.

This is my [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/darnold24/kbc7tma8/10/)

```
<p id = "hi"> inner </p>
var h = $('#hi');
console.log(h);
output is [p#hi]
```

My main objective is to get this array to output:

```
var allDates = $("[data-test='date']"); 
allDates.each(function(item,index){ //each is javascript function
 item[index] = new Date($(this).text());
```

Comment: I don't see what you mean. The JSFiddle works fine for me.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen that's not happening?

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is wrong. You are requesting `var h = $('#id');`, but you're looking for `var h = $('#hi');`

FYI a `<p>` tag inside a table tag is invalid HTML. This should either be inside a th or td or outsize the table tag.

Answer (score 0):

In your html place your P tag in a cell in a table row:

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
    <p id ='hi'>inner</p>
        </td>
        </tr>
  <tr data-test="date">
      12/09/14
    </tr>
    <tr data-test="date">
        12/10/14
    </tr>
        <tr data-test="date">
        12/11/14
    </tr>
        <tr data-test="date">
        12/12/14
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then in your javascript select by the corect identifier - `$('#hi')` in your case:

```
var allDates = $("[data-test='date']");        
var h = $('#hi');
allDates.each(function(item,index)
{ 
     item[index] = new Date($(this).text());     
});    
console.log(allDates);
console.log(h);
```